# How to access the first value from an object in C#3.0

Tags: c#-3.0

How can I access the first value from

```
object t = (object) wsf.LinEst(y.ToArray(), x.ToArray(), false, true);
```

The output is

```
object[1..5, 1..2]}
    [1, 1]: 0.17134831460674155
    [1, 2]: 0.0
    [2, 1]: 0.019612696690686725
    [2, 2]: -2146826246
    [3, 1]: 0.95020429009193053
    [3, 2]: 0.82746057986828336
    [4, 1]: 76.328205128205056
    [4, 2]: 4.0
    [5, 1]: 52.261235955056179
    [5, 2]: 2.7387640449438226
```

**I need to get only [1,1] 's value i.e. 0.17134831460674155**

How to get that.

The linEst return an object only.

I am using C#3.0

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like it's something you can enumerate which returns doubles - although it may not actually implement `IEnumerable<double>`. Try this (with a `using System.Linq;` directive at the top of your code):

```
IEnumerable t = (IEnumerable) wsf.LinEst(y.ToArray(), x.ToArray(), false, true);
double first = t.Cast<double>().First();
```

However, that *won't* work if actually it's returning something like an `int[][]`. Could you tell us more about what it's really returning? Yes, it's declared to just return `object`, but it's clearly returning something more than that. If you know it will always return an `object[,]` with 1-based indexes, you could cast to that:

```
object[,] t = (object[,]) wsf.LinEst(y.ToArray(), x.ToArray(), false, true);
double first = (double) t[1, 1];
```

If you don't know the lower bounds of the array, you can ask for them programmatically of course... but the LINQ way will probably be simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot SIR. It is really helpful. Recently I have purchased your book "C# in Depth". Though I have not yet finished reading the whole book yet.. but what ever I read so far, are a kind of valueable asset to me. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can force a cast to the appropriate type.

Instead of doing:

```
object t = (object) wsf.linEst(etc.)
```

try

```
int[,] t = (int[,]) wsf.linEst(etc.)
```

This is because the linEst function is not simply returning an instance of the Object class.

The output you've included in your question seems to imply that the debugger is able to determine the runtime type of your object t so try and use that information to do the proper cast.

Either that, or wsf.linEst isn't just returning an object and you are adding that `(object)` text which is forcing the return value to be cast to fit into the `object t` variable